# How to set the value of dropdown while adding options in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use below code to add options for dropdown

```
             //HTML CODE
            select(name='folist',  id='folist').
            //JS Code
             for(var i=0;i<data.foNameArray.length;i++){
            var combo = document.getElementById("folist");

            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = data.foNameArray[i];
            option.value =data.foIdArray[i];
             try {
                combo.add(option, null); //Standard 
            }catch(error) {
                combo.add(option); // IE only
            }
            }
```

It perfectly works.Now My doubt is how to select the value while adding like selected="selected".

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [selected property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_selected.asp) of option like this,

```
option.selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`setAttribute`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_setattribute.asp) to do that

```
option = document.createElement("option");
option.setAttribute("selected","selected");
```